# How to POST data to a server with Qt 5?

Tags: c++, web-services, qt, post, qt5

I'm trying to send a bit of json data to a web service using Qt 5.1.1.  There are many examples out there, but almost all are for Qt 4.x, which had a slightly different API.  Here's what I'm trying now:

```
QUrl url("http://...");
QNetworkRequest request(url);
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
QByteArray jsonInPostFormat = "json=" + QUrl::toPercentEncoding(jsonAsString);
jsonInPostFormat.replace("%20","+");
reply = net->post(request, jsonInPostFormat);
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()),   this, SLOT(finishedAddComment()));
```

The above has ... no effect.  If I'm doing things correctly, I seem to not get any response from the server. (I call reply->readALL() in finishedAddComment().)

The service has a test form that works correctly.  I've dumped the headers that it's sending and looked at the html, which is just a standard form with post method specified.

Am I doing something obviously wrong?  Is there a better way, say, using QUrlQuery?

Some way of seeing the raw HTML requests that Qt is actually sending would be super-helpful...

Thanks!
Tyler

Answer (score 3):

Qt5 no longer has the QUrl::encodedQuery() method. Not sure, but from the documentation it might work using QUrl::query() method instead.

Hope it helps.